# Sorting multiple-letter strings

Tags: c#, sorting

I have searched around and been unable to find anything on this, maybe I'm not sure how to phrase my question correctly for Google.

I need to sort a list of strings alphabetically, while handling strings that contain more than one letter.

Given the values `"A", "AA", "B", "BB", "C", "Z", "CC"`

I need the output to be `"A", "B", "C", "Z", "AA", "BB", "CC"`

I've looked into natural sorting, but that doesn't give me the desired results.

Comment: Make it simple, sort on length first, then alphabetically. `list.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ThenBy(s => s)`

Comment: order it by lenght and value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should help you

```
var list = new []{"A", "AA", "B", "BB", "C", "Z", "CC"};
var result = list.OrderBy(x => x.Length).ThenBy(x=> x);
```

The key to solution lies in Ordering the List by Length of each entry,and Then By  actual value.

Output

```
A 
B 
C 
Z 
AA 
BB 
CC
```

Comment: Thanks, I was overthinking it. Will accept as answer when I can.

Comment: Answers which explain how the code presented works generally get more upvotes than those without.

Comment: @HereticMonkey was typing the explanation :)